# Form validation with tag-helper asp.net core 3.1 not show in red

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1, validationerror

I have a simple web application with create page using form with validations.

.cs code:

```
public class OneTask
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required] public string Title { get; set; }
        [Required][MinLength(10)]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        [Required, Range(1,5)] public int Priority { get; set; }
    }
```

.cshtml code:

```
<div class="container" style="width:50%">
    <div asp-validation-summary="All"></div>
    <form asp-page="CreateTask" class="" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="NewTask.Title">Title</label>
            <input asp-for="NewTask.Title" class="form-control" />
// rest of form here...
```

validation scripts:

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

Instead of showing error validations in red it shows it in black.

---------------------------------------------|

- The Title field is required.
- The Description field is required.
- The value '' is invalid.

---------------------------------------------|

Can you help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `class="text-danger"` to change the text color

```
<div class="text-danger" asp-validation-summary="All"></div>
```

[image]

Comment: Isn't it supposed to be the default in asp.net core ? In other applications I did not have to do anything and it was red ...?

Comment: No, it's not the default, you should add it. It is automatically added if you use scaffolding. see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/page?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#the-create-razor-page).